# Rx.NET operator

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I need an operator to allow a stream of booleans to act as a gate for another stream (let values pass when the gate stream is true, drop them when it's false). I would normally use Switch for this, but if the source stream is cold it will keep recreating it, which I don't want.

I also want to clean up after myself, so that the result completes if either of the source or the gate complete.

```
public static IObservable<T> When<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> gate)
{
    var s = source.Publish().RefCount();
    var g = gate.Publish().RefCount();

    var sourceCompleted = s.TakeLast(1).DefaultIfEmpty().Select(_ => Unit.Default);
    var gateCompleted = g.TakeLast(1).DefaultIfEmpty().Select(_ => Unit.Default);

    var anyCompleted = Observable.Amb(sourceCompleted, gateCompleted);

    var flag = false;
    g.TakeUntil(anyCompleted).Subscribe(value => flag = value);

    return s.Where(_ => flag).TakeUntil(anyCompleted);
}
```

Besides the overall verbosity, I dislike that I subscribe to the gate even if the result is never subscribed to (in which case this operator should be a no-op). Is there a way to get rid of that subscribe?

I have also tried this implementation, but it's even worse when it comes to cleaning up after itself:

```
return Observable.Create<T>(
    o =>
    {
        var flag = false;
        gate.Subscribe(value => flag = value);

        return source.Subscribe(
            value =>
            {
                if (flag) o.OnNext(value);
            });
    });
```

These are the tests I'm using to check the implementation:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var output = new List<int>();

    var source = new Subject<int>();
    var gate = new Subject<bool>();

    var result = source.When(gate);
    result.Subscribe(output.Add, () => output.Add(-1));

    // the gate starts with false, so the source events are ignored
    source.OnNext(1);
    source.OnNext(2);
    source.OnNext(3);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new int[0], output);

    // setting the gate to true will let the source events pass
    gate.OnNext(true);
    source.OnNext(4);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 4 }, output);
    source.OnNext(5);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 4, 5 }, output);

    // setting the gate to false stops source events from propagating again
    gate.OnNext(false);
    source.OnNext(6);
    source.OnNext(7);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 4, 5 }, output);

    // completing the source also completes the result
    source.OnCompleted();
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 4, 5, -1 }, output);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    // completing the gate also completes the result
    var output = new List<int>();

    var source = new Subject<int>();
    var gate = new Subject<bool>();

    var result = source.When(gate);
    result.Subscribe(output.Add, () => output.Add(-1));

    gate.OnCompleted();
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { -1 }, output);
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do this by simply using `withLatestFrom` and an appropriate filter and map. Here is a RxSwift implementation: https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/1a70c4f7b8960d06bd7f1bfa81802cc3

Answer (score 1):

Based on the responses from StackOverflow [1], this is what I came up with; it passes both tests plus a third one where I verified that cold observables are only processed once:

```
    public static IObservable<T> When<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> gate)
    {
        return source.Publish(
            ss =>
            {
                var gg = gate.Publish().RefCount();
                var bothCompleted = Observable.Amb(ss.WhenCompleted(), gg.WhenCompleted());

                return gate.Select(g => g ? ss : ss.IgnoreElements()).Switch().TakeUntil(bothCompleted);
            });
    }

    private static IObservable<Unit> WhenCompleted<T>(this IObservable<T> source) =>
        source.Select(_ => Unit.Default).IgnoreElements().Concat(Observable.Return(Unit.Default));
```

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666864/rx-net-gate-operator